# Добавление и изменение элемента в массиве javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.
Массив :

```
var cap = [
      ['a', 'b', 'c', 1],
      ['a', 'q', 'c', 0]   
      ];
```

Нужно добавить в конец массива элемент равный последнему текущему,
при этом изменить у текущего значение 0 на 1, т.е. получить вида :

```
      cap = [
      ['a', 'b', 'c', 1],
      ['a', 'q', 'c', 1],
      ['a', 'q', 'c', 0]   
      ];
```

Делаю так :

```
cap.push(cap[cap.length-1]);
cap[cap.length-1][3]= 1;
```

но получаю все единицы в конце.
Поправьте, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

---

PS

---

первую строку поменял на :

```
cap[cap.length] = cap[cap.length-1];
```

тот же результат, вместо

```
          cap = [
      ['a', 'b', 'c', 1],
      ['a', 'q', 'c', 1],
      ['a', 'q', 'c', 0]   
      ];
```

получаю :

```
          cap = [
      ['a', 'b', 'c', 1],
      ['a', 'q', 'c', 1],
      ['a', 'q', 'c', 1]   
      ];
```

UPD_2
Думаю, что проблема в том, что вставляю элемент не как массив, делал так :

```
cap[cap.length] = '['+cap[cap.length-1]+']';
```

тоже кривизна какая-то, но с *цифрами 0 и 1*  здесь уже ok ...

Comment: Так вы зачем последнему элементу добавляете 1, вам же 0 нужен _cap[cap.length-1][3]= 1;_

Comment: Когда ставлю 0, то получаю алертом : cap = a,b,c,1,a,q,c,0,a,q,c,0

Comment: А у Вас получилось : cap = a,b,c,1,a,q,c,1,a,q,c,0 ?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В массиве cap два последних элемента - это один и тот-же объект (массив):

```
cap[ cap.length - 1 ] === [ cap.length - 2 ] => true
```

нужно клонировать массив:

```
cap[ cap.length ] = cap[ cap.length - 1 ].slice();
cap[ cap.length - 2 ][ 3 ] = 1;
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, так работает.